# How to evaluate given integral in terms of Gamma function?

Tags: integration, gamma-function, approximate-integration

I want to evaluate the below integral
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax^{2}-bx} x^{\alpha -1}\,\mathrm{d}x, ~~~~~~ \operatorname{Re}(\alpha)>0 $$
where $a,b$ are real constants.

Somehow, I want to convert it in the form of the Gamma function but I don't know which substitution will work here. Any help will be appreciated. Please help me if there is any other method to evaluate this integral.

Comment: Mathematica gives the solution in terms of the hypergeometric distribution [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function). Certainly if $b = 0$ you could make a change of variables $x^2 = u$, but with $b \neq 0$, I don't believe you can get it solely in terms of the gamma distribution.

If $\alpha$ is integral, then you can just differentiate $e^{-(ax^2 + bx)}$ with respect to $b$, $\alpha -1$ times and solve the simpler Gaussian integral, but again this is a special situation.

Comment: You can get a *series* if you substitute the power series for $e^{-bx}$ and integrate the result termwise. This is basically a hypergeometric-type series, among the best you can have here.

Comment: Done it in my answer to [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4052291).

Comment: Yeah got it, thanks.