# Computing $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-iky} e^{-c|k|^{\alpha}} |k|^{\beta} dk$

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I want to solve the above integral, where $c >0$, $\beta = 0,2$, $0<\alpha<2 $, $y \in \mathbb{R}$, $k \in \mathbb{R}$. I tried to use the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) adding the semi-circle contour of infinite radius in the half-plane with negative immaginary numbers. 
I don't see singularity inside this half-plane to use for the residue computation; what am I missing?
Any comment is welcome 
[**EDIT**]
As pointed by *metamorphy* I have a branch cut due to $|k|^{\alpha}$ at exponent, so I can't apply the residue theorem. How should I proceed to solve the integral?

Comment: You have a branch cut, not just a singularity ($\implies$ don't expect the residue theorem to apply).

Comment: Thank you metamorphy for your comment. So the problem is $k^{\beta}$ for cases with non integer $\beta$, right? what about the case with $\beta = 0$?

Comment: I modify the question with 2 relevant case with integer $\beta$ values

Comment: This won't help; $|k|^\alpha$ is an issue as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you can get is a [Fox-Wright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function)-type power series.

Substitute $k=c^{-1/\alpha}t$ (essentially reducing to $c=1$) and split $\int_{-\infty}^\infty=\int_{-\infty}^0+\int_0^\infty$ (only $\alpha>0$, $\alpha\neq 1$ and $\Re\beta>-1$ are assumed below). The problem is then reduced to $$f(\alpha,\beta,z)=\int_0^\infty t^\beta\exp(-zt-t^\alpha)\,dt,$$ where $z\in\mathbb{C}$, and $\Re z\geqslant 0$ if $\alpha<1$ (to have a convergent integral). Now, if $\alpha>1$, then $$f(\alpha,\beta,z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-z)^n}{n!}\int_0^\infty t^{n+\beta}e^{-t^\alpha}dt=\frac1\alpha\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-z)^n}{n!}\Gamma\left(\frac{n+\beta+1}{\alpha}\right).$$ If $0<\alpha<1$ and $\Re z>0$, we expand $e^{-t^\alpha}$ this time, and get $\int_0^\infty t^{\eta-1}e^{-zt}\,dt$, which is equal to $\Gamma(\eta)/z^\eta$ even in our case of *complex* $z$ (this is where contour integration [comes into play](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1399848)): $$f(\alpha,\beta,z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int_0^\infty t^{\alpha n+\beta}e^{-zt}\,dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha n+\beta+1)}{z^{\alpha n+\beta+1}}.$$ (The case $\Re z=0$ is covered by taking a limit. The case $\alpha=1$ is trivial.)

Comment: Thank you metamorphy, very clear answer. When you say "*The case Re(z)=0 is covered by taking a limit*" you mean to consider the variable z = x+iy for all the step and only pass in the $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}$ at the end, when the result is reached, right? How can one formally justify this analitic continuation, that is the order's swap between the limit and integral operation?

Comment: The interchange of the limit and the *integral* is easily justified by [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). We also have a "limit $\leftrightarrow$ sum" swap, but that's even easier (the sum is analytic at $z$ not on the negative real axis, if the latter is taken as the branch cut for powers of $z$).